# Как задать свой шаг в цикле?

Tags: javascript

```
`введите код здесь`Как можно задать шаг в цикле вводимый пользователем например
 <SCRIPT LANGUAGE = "JavaScript">
 var a,b;

 a = window.prompt( "Введіть Х кінечне", "10");

 b = window.prompt( "Введіть шаг h ", "2" );

  num=1;
 while (num <= a) {
      document.write(num + "<BR>")
      num=num+b
   }

</SCRIPT>
но так не работает(
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этой конструкции есть синтаксическая ошибка:

```
 document.write(num + "<BR>"); num=num+b
```

и вы промптом принимаете строки, а не числа. parseInt поможет: http://jsfiddle.net/wXgFB/

Answer (score 0):

```
var a,b; 
a = window.prompt( "Введіть Х кінечне", "10");
b = window.prompt( "Введіть шаг h ", "2" );

num=1; 
while (num <= parseInt(a)) { 
    document.write(num + "<BR>");
    num+=parseInt(b); 
}
```